Ubuntu error crash
Every time I launch a program from the terminal (for example Trycycler, htop, flye, etc.), it crashes. I have installed Ubuntu on an external hard disk. I know that is not the best solution, but for what I'm working it should be just fine. I'm working with the assembly of genomes and annotation.
When it crashes an alert says force quit or send problem. Whatever I choose it crashes anyway.

Which version of Ubuntu? And if it is Desktop or Server?

"it crashes" means the program crashes or Ubuntu crashes?

The version of Ubuntu is 24.10 and it is Desktop

While my tool is running from terminal an advice appears and i've only two choices: force quit or send problem. None of them are resolutives.

ou mean that you have installed a daily build of 24.10? Pls read this https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].
